# How do I dynamically open and close angular ui accordion?

Tags: javascript, angularjs, angularjs-directive, angular-ui-bootstrap, angular-routing

I'm fairly new to angularJS. I have an accordion that I am using from Angular ui bootstrap and I am trying to dynamically open and close the accordion based on the `$routeparams` chapter. The problem is since the page reloads every time the user clicks the menu link, the accordion closes. How can I dynamically open and close the accordion based on the route. Here is what I have below.

**Here is the accordion code. This is in the html file. I am using the demo just to test this out. Basically, there are multiple chapters that will be in this menu, and I need the accordion to open when that route is loaded.**

```
<accordion-group is-open="par()">
    <accordion-heading>
        <i class="fa fa-book"></i> Chapter 1<i class="pull-right glyphicon" ng-class="{'glyphicon-chevron-down': status.open, 'glyphicon-chevron-right': !status.open}"></i>
    </accordion-heading>
    <accordion  close-others="oneAtATime">
      <accordion-group is-open="par()">
      <accordion-heading>
        Practice <i class="pull-right glyphicon" ng-class="{'glyphicon-chevron-down': status2.open, 'glyphicon-chevron-right': !status2.open}"></i>
    </accordion-heading>
        <ul ng-controller="mainCtrl">
            <li ng-repeat="words in allTerms1 track by $index"  ng-class="{ 'active': $index == selectedIndex}"><a href  id="{{ $index }}" ng-click="testing($event, 1); PracticeTerm(1); itemClicked($index);">{{words.term}}</a></li>
        </ul>
      </accordion-group>
      <accordion-group is-open="par()">
       <accordion-heading>
        Review<i class="pull-right glyphicon" ng-class="{'glyphicon-chevron-down': status3.open, 'glyphicon-chevron-right': !status3.open}"></i>
    </accordion-heading>
        <ul ng-controller="mainCtrl">
            <li ng-repeat="words in allTerms1 track by $index" ><a href class="{{$index}}" id="{{ $index }}" ng-click="testing($event, 1); ReviewTerm(1);">{{ words.term }}</a></li>
        </ul>
      </accordion-group>
    </accordion>
</accordion-group>
```

**Here is my controller and my attempt to writing a function that opens the accordion based on the route. It doesn't work correctly because when it returns true, the menu is stuck open and the user can no longer close it. I am not sure how I should solve this error.**

```
app.controller('AccordionDemoCtrl', function($scope, $location, $routeParams, $route) {
$scope.change = [{
    'one': 'Chapter-1',
    open: true
}];
$scope.par = function() {
    if ($routeParams.chapters == $scope.change[0].one) {
        return $scope.change[0].open;
    }
};
});
```

**Here is the accordion demo controller**

`   app.controller('AccordionDemoCtrl', function($scope) {
    $scope.oneAtATime = true;

```
$scope.groups = [{
    title: 'Dynamic Group Header - 1',
    content: 'Dynamic Group Body - 1'
}, {
    title: 'Dynamic Group Header - 2',
    content: 'Dynamic Group Body - 2'
}];

$scope.items = ['Item 1', 'Item 2', 'Item 3'];

$scope.addItem = function() {
    var newItemNo = $scope.items.length + 1;
    $scope.items.push('Item ' + newItemNo);
};

$scope.status = {
    isFirstOpen: true,
    isFirstDisabled: false
};
});`
```

Comment: can you put in code where you are using "AccordionDemoCtrl" controller in HTML?

Comment: I am using the accordion in menu.html and loading it from a directive into the page. I will add it in the code.

Answer (score 0):

`par()` is not doing much good without an argument that would be unique for each level.

I have no idea what sort of values you are using in the route so will assume they are like `chapter-NUMBER` and will use that as argument

HTML

```
<accordion-group is-open="par('chapter-1')">
```

JS

```
$scope.par = function(chapter) {
    return $routeParams.chapters === chapter;   
};
```

You could modify this to just pass a number or an index to your `change` object or whatever way you see fit

Comment: In the route, I have two values. $routeParams.chapter = chapter number.

Comment: $routeParams.term = term in json

Comment: I tried your solution and I like it, but how can I switch from true to false and false to true after the accordion is open.

Comment: I put this into the function ` app.controller('AccordionDemoCtrl', function($scope, $location, $routeParams, $route) {
    $scope.par = function(chapter) {
       if($routeParams.chapters == 'Chapter-1'){
     return true;
    }
    };
});`